# How can I batch update jsonb field using Entity Framework Extensions library?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, jsonb, entity-framework-plus, entity-framework-extensions

I use PostgreSQL with EntityFrameworkCore. I need to batch update `jsonb` field. The Z.EntityFramework packages look promising however none of them work for me.

I setup jsonb field with EntityTypeBuilder:

```cs
builder.Property(o => o.Description).HasColumnType(NpgsqlDbType.Jsonb);
```

and with ColumnAttribute:

```cs
[Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
public string Description {get; set;}
```

It works well with a regular update practice. However when I am trying to batch update field using next packages:

```
Install-Package Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore -Version 2.6.0
Install-Package Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore -Version 2.0.2
Install-Package Z.EntityFramework.Classic -Version 7.1.9
```

Using next code:

```cs
 dbContext.AgeBuckets
.Where(o => o.PropertyId == scope.PropertyId)
.UpdateFromQuery(o => //for EF-Plus a method Update()
    new AgeBucket
    {
        Description = serializedDescription //jsonb
    });
```

None of them work for me. I receive next exceptions:
For EF-Plus:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException : 42804: column "Description" is of type jsonb but expression is of type text
```

For EF-Classic and EF-Extensions:

```
System.Exception : Could not find the context from the IQueryable expression. Are you sure this is coming from an Entity Framework Context?
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

Starting from v2.6.2 (for Entity Framework Extensions), `json` and `jsonb` type are now supported for `Batch Update`